# Help with this error while trying to live boot from fresh USB

Tags: live-usb, usb-installation

Followed the tutorial on the site to install Ubuntu on to my flash drive to then "try" while its on the drive before install. Tried three separate flash drives and reinstalling, but I keep getting this error on screen.

[image]

Comment: hi @kambi you need to provide more info. (1) What OS and what software you're using to prepare the flash drive (2) What ISO you're using.. Ubuntu version and flavor if any. (3) BIOS/UEFI info of the PC you're trying to boot. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! Thanks for the heads up. :) Used a notably FRESH Windows 10 install to create the USB device, and I used ubuntu-22.04.3 and Rufus to create the drive. I am also using an ASUS ROG BIOS running version 0403 with a 4080 and a 13900k

Comment: I'm not in front of Windows PC right now but from memory, in Rufus you've to select GPT-UEFI/MBR-BIOS. Your PC sounds fairly new with 13900K, so it should be GPT-UEFI. What options you chose? Thanks.

Comment: I used the default options, so MBR and BIOS/UEFI. Ill give it a shot with GPT-UEFI though, thanks!

Comment: Another thing to note: It's always better idea to verify `sha256sum` once you've downloaded the ISO. There are many tools for Windows but my preferred way is to simply install `7zip` from (for most/recent PCs, it should be 64-bit version): `https://www.7-zip.org/`. You'll need to right click on ISO file, look for 7zip, and there'll an option to generate sha256sum, which you can verify with Ubuntu website where you've downloaded the ISO. Thanks.

Comment: After trying those settings, validating, and redownloading Ubuntu and revalidating, Im still getting the error as seen in the posts pic. Not sure what else I could do.

Comment: (1) When the PC boots up from flash drive, do you see an option: `Use Safe Graphics`? You can try that (2) If you're just experimenting for the first time, you can try other flavors, like Ubuntu MATE. Also just for a test, you could try newer version 23.04: `https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/amd64/lunar/`. Thanks.